# Best way to describe my role for LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin, job-description

Not Sure if this is the correct area to post this, if not please let me know and I will re-direct it.

I'm 21 and i'm a "Junior System Administrator" for a Post Production Company, I never knew how important LinkedIn was until I saw how many people we employed through it, I want to tailor my current job role description to the best of my ability but I'm struggling, I don't know what to include and what to leave out, what is too much/little, currently it's in CV form aka bullet points, which I've heard is a massive mistake to do.

Edit: I was pursuing a Degree in computer Science but dropped out after 1 year to pursue work in another IT company, so I need things like this to strengthen my worth I guess.

Here is a brief overview of what I do at the moment, any help is appreciated!

I maintain and manage our Windows Server, creating & deleting users when needed, creating group policies for departments and managing users permissions, I manage our License Servers,these servers host all of the licenses for the software we use, I install and update all necessary components when needed, the network i manage comprises of 60+ computers that I deploy software/general updates on and troubleshoot/solve any problems that may arise.

I manage a GPU render farm (50 GPUS spread across multiple boxes) that we use to render projects with, I wrote scripts/setup our farm so that it auto logs in, opens all required programs and maps all network drives automatically even after a crash/reboot.

I'm currently planning a company wide OS move to Linux(Currently running windows) this involves changing setting up a Domain Controller, Web Server, DHCP/DNS Server, re-mapping the Entire network and Automation of software deployment and updates.

So my question is, how do I make all of that look nice/tailored, as if it were to roll of the tongue essentially, descriptions and describing myself/things I do are not my strong point at all.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you're asking is off-topic here as it's basically personalised resume advice. That's contrary to StackExchange's goal of collecting Q&A that's useful for more than just the OP. Consider asking in [chat] for personal assistance or resume reviews as the rules are more relaxed there and there are usually some people there who don't mind helping out or providing advice.

Comment: Can you please fix up your grammar here? You're asking for professional advice on writing from professionals, I just think it wouldn't hurt for you to capitalize "i" and fix typos.

Comment: @djechlin they're capitalized now, any other grammar mistakes I missed? wrote it hurriedly so missed some things.

Comment: linkedin > LinkedIn. "mi" -> "I'm." The point is act like you care about your writing, slow down and think, take some pride in writing clearly (you have rambling sentences and I doubt you reread this to yourself). Normally I wouldn't scold someone so much but you're literally complaining about not being good at "describing yourself" so I think professional writing would be a start.

Comment: If I didn't care I would not be asking for advice on the matter,I wouldn't have fixed the spelling mistakes, I acknowledge that i'm not great at writing which is why I'm looking for advice, you could have just said, hey you should work on this rather than attempting to "scold" me, I didn't realize asking for advice about a topic you know you're not great at, was complaining! Cheers for the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn is a different creature compared to resumes, when looking for a job or a candidate for a job. First and foremost, you need to hone your profile containing the right keywords, where you possibly seek employment in the future. Looks like "Windows Server" needs to be prominent, "Transition from Windows to Linux" is a good one as well. "GPU rendering", "Active Directory" are other things come to mind.

Research what people like you did on their profile, especially one with progressively higher ranking positions in their profile timeline. Try to imitate them.

Describing your role is not as important as you might think. But make sure in every role, you are not only listing things that you had touched or technologies that you dealt with, but also accomplishments. Like *"managed 50 windows servers and in less than a year, consolidated them under 10 virtual machines running RedHat Linux, saving the company $10,000 per year in hardware support contracts."*

On your current role description, try to make it brief but not something that people confuse with, say a computer salesman.

Google the phrase "Best suggestions for building a linkedin profile" and you will find useful information.

Comment: To be fair this is exactly the advice you should follow for writing a resume.

Comment: @MelBurslan that's part of the mistake I'm making, I'm essentially just listing what technologies I have worked with rather than what I have accomplished with them,which in the end just looks like a list of buzzwords.
I'll definitely have a look through other professionals accounts and see what I can put together, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your paper resume into LinkedIn. It's that simple.

I'm not saying writing a resume is easy, I'm just saying you should take all the advice you know for writing a resume and apply it to LinkedIn, via Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.